# Plug in estimator for variance from Wasserman

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

In All of Statistics by Larry Wasserman, page 100, Example 7.11, the example is asking about the plug in estimator of the variance for a linear functional (i.e. the plug in estimator for $\sigma^2=T(F)=\mathbb{V}(X)=\int x^2 dF(x)-(\int xdF(x))^2$).

It says the plug in estimator is

\begin{align}
\hat{\sigma}^2 &= \int x^2 d\hat{F}(x)-\left(\int xd\hat{F}(x)\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X}_n)^2
\end{align}

Here, $F$ is the distribution that we pick samples $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ from and $\hat{F}$ is the empirical distribution function generated from these sample.

I am confused about the algebra going from 2nd to 3rd line above. I feel like it should be
\begin{align}
\hat{\sigma}^2 &= \int x^2 d\hat{F}(x)-\left(\int xd\hat{F}(x)\right)^2\\
&=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2\\
&\color{red}{=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2-(\bar{X}_n)^2}
\end{align}

Can someone help me figure out what I am seeing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

\begin{align}
\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \left( \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^2 &= \frac1n \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \frac1n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right)^2\right)\\
&=\frac1n \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \frac1n\left( n\bar{X}\right)^2\right)\\
&=\frac1n \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - n\left( \bar{X}\right)^2\right)\\
&=\frac1n \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - 2n\left( \bar{X}\right)^2+n\bar{X}^2\right)\\
&=\frac1n \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - 2\bar{X}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i+\sum_{i=1}^n\bar{X}^2\right)\\
&= \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar{X})^2
\end{align}